# oAuth Scope for Google Sheets Sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a sidebar for my Google Sheets that shows some information about the data quality, i.e. it runs a custom function.

The setup is pretty standard with a sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <p>Data</p>
                <button onClick="getData()">Get data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="output">

        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function onFailure(error) {
            var div = document.getElementById('output');
            div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
        }

        function getData() {
            google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).getData()
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

which is created so

```
function mainSidebar() {
    const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar').evaluate()
    html.setTitle('My Tools')

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html)
}
```

and triggered by a custom menu item.

This all works, however, when I click on the button, I get the error "Authorisation is required to perform that action.". Checking the error log on https://console.cloud.google.com/logs doesn't tell me any more as to WHICH oAuth scope I am missing.

My application manifest has the following scopes

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
```

Can anyone either tell me which scope I need or how I can find out which one is failing?

The function I am calling looks like this:

```
function getData() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()
}
```

P.s. Because this runs in the context of a sheet/sidebar, I cannot "manually run" it. So the popup never happens.

Comment: Go [here](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and remove your app. Reauth again.

Comment: Aside from @TheMaster's recommendation, can you try running the function `getData` from Google Apps Script and see if the authorization message shows up?

Comment: @TheMaster, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this did not work. I have added removed all actual data generation and have limited the getData() function to writing a JavaScript object to the Logger, and returning it. Although the log shows the output, I still get the auth error.

Comment: @Saddles, running the getData() inside die IDE does not show any authorisation message ...

Comment: That's unfortunate, and I'm sorry to hear that. I tried what you've provided and it's working for me. Can you try to create a new Google Sheet, copy and paste your codes, and run it through Google Apps Script to check if it's going to work? You can also run another Google service such as [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app), [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), or [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) to see if that's going to give you any progress.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the user, it works for everyone else ...